# Are banks in the US allow to publicly disclose the amount of the checks a bank customer is trying to cash in at the bank along with the customer name?

Tags: united-states, privacy, banking

I read on https://abcnews.go.com/amp/US/black-man-sues-detroit-bank-alleging-racial-discrimination/story?id=68484056:

> Gordon said a confidentially clause in his settlement with his former employer, Enterprise Leasing Co. of Detroit, prevented her from disclosing the amount of the checks. But TCF Bank told the Detroit Free Press that Thomas presented three checks written from Enterprise that day: one for $59,000, one for $27,000 and one for $13,000.

Are banks in the United States allow to publicly disclose the amount of the checks a bank customer is trying to cash in at the bank along with the customer name?

Comment: Of course not, unless the reporter lifted that information from the initial police report and misreported the source.